# Adding a new subscription endpoint to a Facebook app gives "Unable to verify provided url"

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

How can I find out what's happening?

My endpoint returns a 200 OK as it says it should in the documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.5#setup

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the response needs to be the challenge string